# Pagination problem in custom post type used as front page

Tags: custom-post-types, pagination

I am working on a theme with custom post type.
the issue currently is that i am saving the layout files in a folder called templates.. and in front-page.php i am using an options check to see which type of layout did the user selected from theme panel.. and include that file..
Right now in the custom post type template, pagination isn't working.. i am using this loop :

```
    global $wp_query;

$temp = $wp_query;
$wp_query= null;
$wp_query = new WP_Query();
$wp_query->query('post_type=portfolio&paged='.$paged);
                if ($wp_query->have_posts()) : while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post(); 
    ......
    <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
    ..    
    <?php 
                if (function_exists("pagination")) {
        pagination($additional_loop->max_num_pages);}
            ?>  
    <?php $wp_query = null; $wp_query = $temp;?>
```

The pagination shows up but shows link as /page/2/  .. which gives 404 on running.. in my opinion it is showing the main query's page 2, as not many posts added so giving 404.

I have also tried :

```
$paged = 1;  
if ( get_query_var('paged') ) $paged = get_query_var('paged');  
if ( get_query_var('page') ) $paged = get_query_var('page');
```

Didn't work..
My Custom Post Register Structure :

```
function my_custom_post_portfolio() {
    $labels = array(
        'name'               => _x( 'Portfolio', 'post type general name' ),
        'singular_name'      => _x( 'Portfolio', 'post type singular name' ),
        'add_new'            => _x( 'Add New', 'book' ),
        'add_new_item'       => __( 'Add New Item' ),
        'edit_item'          => __( 'Edit Item' ),
        'new_item'           => __( 'New Portfolio Item' ),
        'all_items'          => __( 'All Items' ),
        'view_item'          => __( 'View Items' ),
        'search_items'       => __( 'Search Portfolio' ),
        'not_found'          => __( 'No Portfolio found' ),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No Portfolio found in the Trash' ), 
        'parent_item_colon'  => '',
        'menu_name'          => 'Portfolio'
    );
    $args = array(
        'labels'        => $labels,
        'description'   => 'Holds our Portfolio and product specific data',
        'public'        => true,
        'menu_position' => 5,
        'supports'      => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'comments' ),
        'has_archive'   => true,
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'portfolio', 'with_front' => true ),
        '_builtin' =>  false, // It's a custom post type, not built in!
        'query_var' => true,
        'taxonomies' => array('portfolio', 'post_tag') // this is IMPORTANT
    );

    register_post_type( 'Portfolio', $args );   
}
add_action( 'init', 'my_custom_post_portfolio' );
```

Help is appreciated!
Thanks :)

Comment: see [`pre_get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is hard to say with 100% certainty but I think the problem is your  use of [`query_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts). Here is what I believe is happening:

1. The Main query runs with the default parameters and loads your page
2. You clobber the main query with `query_posts`
3. You generate pagination based on the clobbered main query
4. You click a link
5. The unclobbered main query tries to sort out what you want (remember, your `query_posts` can't run until WordPress loads the template)
6. And fails and you get a 404

Just don't use `query_posts`. If you ever think you have found a legitimate place to use `query_posts` you are almost certainly wrong. The Core is the only thing that should be running that function.

If you must alter the main query use a filter on `pre_get_posts`.

```
function alter_query_wpse_99042($qry) {
  $qry->set('posts_per_page',6);
  $qry->set('post_type','portfolio');
}
add_action('pre_get_posts','alter_query_wpse_99042');
```

However, based on your post type registration settings it looks like WordPress should be building the archive for you. I am not sure why you need to be constructing a query at all, except maybe to change `posts_per_page`. [You can customize the generated archive by making a file named `archive-portfolio.php` and saving it to the theme directory.](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Custom_Post_Types_display) `single-portfolio.php` does the same with single post-type displays. Those files are loaded automatically.

Comment: Hello, thanks it fixed the issue but break everything else, i mean what u did is altered the main query, as i am using 4 different templates.. it is making all queries post type as portfolio. so as i gathered from your answer, what i need to do is not use query_post. let me try it and get back to you

Comment: That is sample code. You will need to add the appropriate logic to make sure it works only where you want it to.

Comment: just updated the question with custom query.. can you please check. and now pagination stopped showing up.

Comment: That is not what I said to do. Some (most) of the pagination functions operate on the `global $wp_query` object. See: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/77661/next-posts-link-works-only-with-original-wp-query/77666#77666 Also see: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/92520/wordpress-pagination-on-custom-script/92559#92559

Comment: Tried few variations as per the links your provided. it seems i am getting this issue because files are included in the front-page.php depending on what layout user is selecting from the theme option.. maybe?

Comment: k as you clarified in your last comment, i used gloabl wp_query to for the loop and made changes according to the links you provided. but its still not working, see updated question please.

Comment: Still, those are workarounds. The best way to do this is to alter the query with `pre_get_posts`. I think you are charging along in the wrong direction.

Comment: Hey dude again, sorry , i made the answer as marked, but as i am using the pre get.. it makes my menus stop working... really strange.. please cehck my code : function alter_query_wpse_99042($qry) {
$options = get_option('romeo');
if($options['w3t_layout_option'] == 'portfolio2' || $options['w3t_layout_option'] == 'portfolio3' || $options['w3t_layout_option'] == 'portfolio4'){
  $qry->set('post_type','portfolio');
  }
}
add_action('pre_get_posts','alter_query_wpse_99042');

Comment: [Edit] you question with the code.

Comment: looks like i am panicking too much today... added && $qry->is_main_query() in the if statement check , and it fixed the issue. sorry to bug you